# import images from application folder

Tags: ios, image, import

Is there anyway of importing images from an application document folder to the computer? I'm aware that the images can be saved in the photo albums, but since i can't create my own album and don't care to mix the photos with "personal" photos i'd prefere a way to import them from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download your documents directory using itunes. There is a post related to this on stackoverflow search for it